# bash fetch text from a page throwing away all html

Tags: html, bash, url, cron, wget

I would like to create a function that would get info from a site and display it in the same way as on that web page. i.e. throw away all HTML tags, or convert them (in a simple way) so that the end result is just the text of the page.

For example, I would like to have a function that just displays the contents of this site on the console, but not as unreadable/jumbled html output. Are there simple ways to fully or partially achieve something like this?

```
intro-cron() {
    URL=http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html
    content=$(wget $URL -q -O -)
    echo $content
}
```

Comment: For static pages, `lynx -dump $URL` looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, perfect, thanks.